# Trying to automate a series of steps which include connecting to server and logging in

Tags: windows, perl, networking

I am trying to automate a series of steps using a Perl script. In this I need to connect to a server (which manually I do by opening `putty.exe`), login to it and then execute some commands.

I tried it using `NET::SSH::Perl` but commands are not getting executed (I am not getting any error message here). Is there any other way I can fix it and proceed or is it something I can't do using Perl?

```
$host= "mhadli";
$user= "rshukla";
$pass= "******";
$cmd = "ll";
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($user, $pass);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you should show some code and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: No change. Is there any other way to to open Putty.exe and login to it using script? Or I need to follow this step only?

Comment: I am not using cygwin executing perl script fom CMD is it required to run it from cygwin??

Comment: Yes. Use Cygwin. Also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689945/how-do-we-configure-ssh-using-perl-in-windows

Comment: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare all of your variables with `my`. You should also run the module in debug mode by creating the object using `Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, debug => 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `expect` (created for/by the great `tcl` langage). It was created with exactly that kind of usage in mind.  You can invoke an expect script from perl.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that if you are working on a machine where you can access a shell... you can run shell commands in perl using the very simple `` operator:

```
`ssh 08.736.fak.eip -l mylogin/pwd`
```

This might suffice to login to the machine - and then you can continue on doing whatever perl you need to do in the rest of the script.

Also I suggest adding

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

atop the script.

Answer (score 0):

instead of Net::SSH::Perl that is old, unmaintained and really difficult to install, use [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2) or the not-yet-mature-but-easier-to-use [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aAny)!