# error in openSSH on windows

Tags: perl, openssh

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;

$Net::OpenSSH::debug |= 16;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(host=>'xx.xx.xx.xx',
                            user => 'xxxx',
                            password => 'xxxx'
);

$ssh->error and die "SSH connection failed: " . $ssh->error;
my $command = "ls";
my @out = $ssh->capture($command);
print @out;
```

the above prog gives following error

```
SSH connection failed: unable to determine home directory for uid 0 at ./ssh.pl
line 12.
```

I am using avtivestate perl (v5.12.3)

although i give another user instead of root it gives same error.
I have centos 6.4 on host.
can anyone help me?

Comment: It is not clear what OS you are using locally (where your Perl is running). Is it CentOS or is CentOS running on the remote host you are trying to reach through ssh ?

Comment: @Ouki I have windows as my client and i Hv centos on remote host.that i am trying to reach via ssh.

Comment: Then Miller got the right answer.

Comment: Net::OpenSSH does not work on Windows. Your best options there are probably [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2) and [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Any) (on top of Net::SSH2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [`Net::OpenSSH`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH):

> On the other hand, Net::OpenSSH does not work on Windows, not even under Cygwin.

For an alternative solution: [`How do we configure SSH using Perl in Windows?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689945/how-do-we-configure-ssh-using-perl-in-windows)