# Unable to connect to Linux host from Windows server using Net::SSH::Any Perl module

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to connect to a linux host from a Windows server with SSH using Net::SSH::Any Perl module, but Getting the below error.

**Code**

```
use Net::SSH::Any;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', user => 'xxx', password => 'xxxx');

my @out = $ssh->capture('ls');

print @out;
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\spectrum\Desktop>perl SSH_Any.pl
PTYs are not supported on Windows at SSH_Any.pl line 5.
```

Can somebody please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689945/how-do-we-configure-ssh-using-perl-in-windows

Comment: if Net::SSH::Any uses backend Net::SSH2, then why does it need cygwin ?